# how to compile exception in java

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

Why won't this compile and how do I get it to compile in the java language? Isn't the point of the try/catch block to get a potential error to compile?

```
try 
{
  int b = "HI";
}
catch(Exception e)
{
  System.out.println(e);
  System.out.println('success');
}
```

I get this message instead of the expected result:

mainTest.java:19: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int
      int b = "HI";

Comment: Compilation errors and exceptions are not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- **b** is an `Integer`, you cannot assign a `String` literal to it. **That's a Compile-time error, not a Runtime one**. *(Exceptions don't handle compilation errors)*

2- The `catch` block is used to intercept any exceptions thrown by the `try` code block, which it does not.

For the example:

```
try {
    int a = 5;
    int b = 0;
    int c = a/b; // Division by 0, throws an ArithmeticException
}
catch (ArithmeticException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: "Exceptions don't handle compilation errors"

thanks, that answered my question and clarified a lot of my misunderstandings.